# Move Server Side Code to Client Querying MongoDB

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, mongodb, meteor

So I have developed some server side code to query my `mongodb` now my issue is I need to store that data on my local machine (amazon aws), so I can analyze the data. What tools can I use to accomplish this? I have two goals:

Short Term: Data analysis I don't need a UI to do this but I do need to write some scripts to query and then store data for analysis

Long Term: Do the above but now there is a web interface with a client facing application

I'm aware I can use things like Ruby on Rails, nodejs, or meteor to access mongo since they have gems and npm packages to do so - my issue is how to start guides or tutorials would be helpful. As far as my short term goal wouldn't it be excessive to have a full web interface to do this? Could I just write a single script in Ruby or JavaScript that does this?

Context: My full workflow is to query `mongodb` from `aws` store the data for analysis and push it out to `cartoDB` the script I have been running server side and now I need to run on client side:

```
var start = new Date(2013, 2, 13, 22, 0, 0);
var end = new Date(2013, 2, 13, 23, 0, 0);

while (start < end) {
    var newDate = start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + 5);
    start = new Date(newDate);

    db.getCollection("_User").find().forEach(function (myDoc) {
        var a = db.Data.find({user: myDoc.username, "_created_at": {$lt: start}}).sort({" _created_at": -1}).limit(1);
        if (a.length() > 0) {
            print(a[0]["battery"])
        }
    });

    print(start)
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason not to use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) and have the data analyzed server side? From what I can see, your needs are trivial.

Comment: Nice I wasn't aware of this framework I'll take a look at it and see - there is no reason to not have the data analyze server side if possible. Are these serve side computations then run as a .js file or another method? [the mongodb's are on mongolab]

Comment: Those are basically special queries. So no need for an external js. Simply run them from your application or on the shell.

Comment: That's what I have been doing - my issue though is great it outputs the results on the CLI - how do I save those results then to explore to some other place? From what I found on SO that didn't look that feasible - so I figured make some local script to do it or make the actual web app. Unless I can do it in the CLI.

Comment: You might want o have a look at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/